# SSRS Report on PowerBI Server behaving strangely

Tags: reporting-services, expression, powerbi, ssrs-2012

Recently we moved several Reports from a classic SSRS environment to a PowerBI Server. All works fine - except one error I can't solve!

The report provides an overview over occured errors. The errors are split into critical (prio 1) and moderate (prio 2) errors and informative messages (prio 3). This is the grouping structure of my Dataset as well.

Each group has a "header" / first row, which contains an expression, which displays something like `Prio 1 ([number of Prio 1 Errors])`, where [number of Prio 1 errors] is evaluated via `LOOKUP` to another Dataset. This item is used for collapsing and expanding of the group.

Now the error: in the classic report server environment everything works fine, but the PowerBI server messes up this header as soon as the collapsing / expanding is performed. When the report is called, the display is as expected something like `(+)Prio 1 (53 records)`, bus as soon as I click the `(+)`, it is changed to `(-)#Error`. However, if I undo the action, it still stays `(+)#Error`.

My expression on the mentioned item is `=Fields!ResultRating.Value & "   (" & LOOKUP(Fields!ResultRating.Value, Fields!Severity.Value, Fields!ResultCount.Value, "ds_ErrorOverview") & ")"`. If I remove the part between the brackets, the displayed text stays `Prio 1 ()`, no matter if I perform collapsing or not.

Any help would be highly apreciated.

Comment: `=Fields!ResultRating.Value & "   (" & LOOKUP(Fields!ResultRating.Value, Fields!Severity.Value, Fields!ResultCount.Value, "ds_ErrorOverview") & ")"`  looks fishy to me. Do you want to display both values? Like `=Fields!ResultRating.Value & " / " & LOOKUP(Fields!ResultRating.Value, Fields!Severity.Value, Fields!ResultCount.Value, "ds_ErrorOverview")` ?

Comment: `Fields!ResultRating.Value` is the priority (1 = critical, 2 = moderate, 3 = informative) and `Fields!ResultCount.Value` is the second value which is the number of records. This is stored within another DataSet which basically consists of three rows with two columns: Priority and count. Therefore the Lookup which then compares `Fields!ResultRating.Value`with  `Fields!Severity.Value` and returns `Fields!ResultCount.Value`. As mentioned: on the report server it works as designed...